# reloading the page after the ok button in sweetalert

Tags: jquery

I am using sweetAlert code to reload the page after i click the OK, but it just appears for 4 seconds and then reload the page, how can i fix it.

my Code:

```
localStorage.setItem("swal",swal({title:"Good job!", text:"Thanks For your Quotation, we will get back to you soon!",
                        type:"success",timer:4000,showConfirmButton: true}));
                        location.reload();
                        localStorage.getItem("swal");
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to execute actions on the "OK" button try this:

```
swal({...}).then(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

If you also have a "Cancel" button in your modal, you'll want to confirm that the "OK" button was indeed pressed:

```
swal({...}).then(okay => {
  if (okay) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

the variable "okay" is true if the user clicked the "OK" button, otherwise is false

## Update

try to update your code with this:

```
localStorage.setItem("swal",swal({ title:"Good job!", 
                                   text:"Thanks For your Quotation, we will get back to you soon!",
                                   type:"success",
                                   showConfirmButton: true
                                  }).then(function(){
                                      window.location.reload();
                                  })
                    );
localStorage.getItem("swal")
```

I made a fiddle, [click here to test it](https://jsfiddle.net/Evolutionlab/v1nc5xfz/) as you can see everything works, when you press "OK" the page will reload (opening another time the swal, you have to handle the reload in your code)

Comment: this is in the docs, how can i use it in proper syntax, can you show any sample